# Crontab tasks not sending notification

Tags: cron, kali-linux, python, notifications

So, I wrote a python script to get me some docs from a website and I want it to send notification when a doc is downloaded, so I used `notify2` module to do so.

It works fine when I run the script from terminal, but form crontab does not.

**Note:** I am doing this in `Kali Linux`.

**Edit:** I created a `.sh` file to get the environment vars with this content

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
```

and when I run it from terminal `./*.sh` it gives me the following:

```
export COLORTERM='truecolor'
export DISPLAY=':1'
export HOME='/root'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LOGNAME='root'
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
export MAIL='/var/mail/root'
export OLDPWD='/home'
export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
export PWD='/home/hadi'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export SHLVL='1'
export SUDO_COMMAND='/usr/bin/bash'
export SUDO_GID='1000'
export SUDO_UID='1000'
export SUDO_USER='hadi'
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export USER='root'
export XAUTHORITY='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
export _='./allow.sh'
```

and when I add a crontab job to run the `.sh` file using this line:

`* * * * * /home/hadi/allow.sh >> /home/hadi/Desktop/allowed.txt`

the text in `allowed.txt` is only this:

```
export HOME='/root'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LOGNAME='root'
export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin'
export PWD='/root'
export SHELL='/bin/sh'
```

so, I guess it is not getting all vars!

Comment: What's your crontab entry?

Comment: Cron jobs are independent of the user's login session, so they won't have access to the notification service on the session D-Bus, unless you take some steps to allow the cron job to get a copy of the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from a logged-in session. Have you done so? Also, what should your script do if cron runs it when someone else, or nobody at all is currently logged in?

Comment: Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). 
  
One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
 Read `man 5 crontab`.
  
Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
  
Since the `command` part

Comment: @roaima I tried this entry at the first time `* * * * * python3 /home/hadi/Documents/PythonProjects/autoDegreesChecking/main.pyw` (not working)

then I tried this out, `* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 && XAUTHORITY="/home/hadi/.Xauthority" && XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000" && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus && pythpn3 /home/hadi/Documents/PythonProjects/autoDegreesChecking/appointment.py
` (did not work either)

Comment: @telcoM I guess I have done that, but I did it many times in diffrenet ways because I searched a lot on the net about that, so I got confused about the correct way (also I am new to Kali Linux)..

So, could you give me the right way to allow the cron job get a copy of the env var `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, you could see my above comment about what I did.

Comment: The command part of a `crontab` line is a simple command, not your complex command. Wrap your setup in a `bash` script and invoke that from `crontab`.

Comment: @HaDiAyOuB The problem is that your Dbus session will only exist while you're logged in at all, and depending on your setup it might change every time. Your best bet would be to add something to your `.bashrc` that checks wither the variable exists and if so writes it to a file that the script you invoke from `cron` then reads.